# How to coordinate angular authentication service and socket service

Tags: javascript, angular, sockets, websocket, socket.io

My current requirement is that the user enters the username and password, and when the back-end authentication passes, a token will be generated and sent to the front-end, and the front-end will get the token before passing it to the socket to create a connection. The implementation of socket connection service is similar to this?

Is there an example of integrating authentication service and socket service?

```
export class SocketConnectionService {
  socket: io.Socket;

connect(myToken) {
    this.socket = io.io(`${environment.serverUrl}`, {
      auth: {
        token: myToken
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, you described it perfectly well yourself. You have to wait for your authentication service to complete before passing the returned token to the socket service. So what exactly is the question? How to implement the auth service?

Comment: Yes, I have no idea on how to implement auth service with this socket connection service of mine

Comment: This question is too broad. You should read tutorials on the general topic and learn more about authentication - then you will start seeing a way of implementing this. When you then run into specific problems you're welcome to present your approach here and to ask for help regarding the specific problems.